# How to check an id being tied to its related table for only one value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables in which I need to check whether UCCID is tied to only one BUYID as part of testing. UCCID should be unique for my table. But BUyid can have multiple UCCID. But UCCID should be tied to unique (only one) BUYID.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EquipmentBase](
           [EDAEquipmentId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
           [BuyID] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
           [EqtAE] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
           [EqtSn] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
           [EqtSz] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
           [EqtUccYr] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
           [EqtUnit] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
           [EqtValue] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
           [UccID] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
           CONSTRAINT [PK__EquipmentBase] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
           [_EDAEquipmentId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO


    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[activityBase](
           [activityId] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL,
           [UccID] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
           [ASCity] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
           [ASClass] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
           [ASComp] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
           [ASID] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
           [ASState] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
           [BuyADR1] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
           [BuyADR2] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
           [BuyID] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
           [UccCom] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
           [UccDate] [DATETIME] NULL,
           [UccFips2] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
           [UccStatus] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
           [UccTransID] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
           CONSTRAINT [PK__activityBase] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
           [activityId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
```

I tried the below query but I am not getting the result for what I am looking into? Can anyone help pls? I expect the below query to return 0 so that UCCID is tied to single BUYID.

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.activityBase ab
        JOIN (SELECT eb.BuyID FROM dbo.EquipmentBase eb
        WHERE eb.UccID IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY eb.BuyID
        HAVING COUNT(eb.BuyID)=1)c
        ON c.BuyID = ab.BuyID
```

Comment: You sag "UCCID should be unique for my table." For both tables?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly (and your question is not super clear), if you want to identify any values of `UccID` for which records exist with more than one different value of `BuyID`(across both of your tables), you could use:

```
SELECT UccId, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT BuyID, UccID FROM EquipmentBase
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT BuyID, UccID FROM activityBase
) AS DistinctCombos
GROUP BY UccId HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This uses a subquery in the `FROM` clause to return all combinations of the two fields across both tables, then inspects those results to find any `UccID` values which have more than one distinct `BuyID` value against them.